# Modernizr classes are not applied to the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I'm using `Modernizr` to detect browser features. But this time when I started a project it seems that `Modernizr` does not apply its classes to the `html`.

I just realized when I replace my local source to the JS:

`<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>`

with:

`<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/1.7/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>`

Then it works like a charm. Why local copy of `Modernizr` does not work?

CHMODS are 777 and I'm viewing the source by `Shift+CTRL+I` in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like your build doesn't have the `cssclasses` option included from the builder.

[image]

Comment: Yes! I thought that this is only for adding a prefix to the classes and I unchecked it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you I thought the same thing it was driving me nuts!